# babel-plugin-transform-remove-console plugin not working with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-plugin

I have simply followed the guide provide by babel [babel-plugin-transform-remove-console](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console) but it didn't work.

I have

- installed package `npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev`
- created babel.config.json file

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

and now I am stuck. Anyone can help me with this, I will be thankful!